# Apex: conditional get/set

Tags: apex, class

If I have a class that starts like this:

```
public class BrowseController {
    String name = 'something';
}
```

How can I write it so it changes based on a boolean's value?

```
public class BrowseController {
    String name { if boolean == true 'something' } else { 'something_else'};
}
```

What's the correct syntax here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class BrowseController {
    String name { 
                  get {
                         return (booleanVar ? 'something' : 'something else');
                      }  
                  set;
                }
}
```

Ternary operators are helpful in this. `get` always require `return` of same data type.

Comment: I need to wrap the return in a `get {}`, but still, excellent help. Thanks again.